# Laravel 5.7 make bash alias

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a shortcut for artisan commands, to write

`pa` instead of `php artisan`

I found many topics talking about creating `.bashrc` file

```
if [ -f $HOME/.bash_aliases ]
then
  . $HOME/.bash_aliases
fi
```

But I don't understand

I have three questions:

1. Where should I put this file and how I can execute it?
2. Is this file will be available for a certain project only?
3. Can I make it available for all my projects?

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's explained very well in this [link](https://laravel-news.com/bash-aliases).

To summarize:

1. Edit `~/.bashrc` file and add:

   ```
   if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
       . ~/.bash_aliases
   fi
   ```
2. Create new file called `.bash_aliases` in your home directory
3. Add your alias to `.bash_aliases` file e.g: `alias pa="php artisan"`
4. from your terminal run `source ~/.bashrc` or restart it (close and reopen).

---

for your questions:

1. in your home directory.
2. will be available for all projects of this user who modified these files.
3. it's already available.

Comment: 1- I didn't find the file .bashrc in my project .. should I create it manually ? .. 2 - the home directory .. is that the public folder ?

Comment: it's hidden in your home directory. just `cd ~` and `ll` to find it or `Ctrl + h` to show hidden files in your home.